# Trouble Connecting to Remote LDAP Server using Zend_Ldap

Tags: zend-framework, ldap

We're attempting to use Zend_Ldap to authenticate users to our website using the subscriber's LDAP server.  We have a couple clients already setup and working but when we added a new client the connection just hung and after 30 minutes(!) we received the following (less than helpful) error:

> 0x51 (Can't contact LDAP server): ldap://x.x.x.x

The only other debugging step I know is to use `ldapsearch`.  If I do just `ldapsearch -h x.x.x.x` nothing happens for a very long time (I don't feel like waiting 30 minutes but I'm guessing I'll get the "Can't connect to LDAP server" error) and if I run it using `-d5` I get the following output.

```
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://x.x.x.x)
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP x.x.x.x:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying x.x.x.x:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({) ber:
ber_flush2: 31 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x7f9ad5666410 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7f9ad5666410 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f9ad5666410 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7f9ad5666410 Connections:
* host: x.x.x.x  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Mon Jul 13 09:14:44 2015


** ld 0x7f9ad5666410 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f9ad5666410 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f9ad5666410 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f9ad5666410 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f9ad5666410 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f9ad5666410 NULL
ldap_int_select

<20+ minute delay>

read1msg: ld 0x7f9ad5666410 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

The client's LDAP server is Windows Server 2008 R2 and we're using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS with ldapsearch from OpenLDAP 2.4.28.

Any suggestions on what to troubleshoot next?  My guess is it's somewhere in the clients network but I want to check my end as much as possible before I start asking them.

**Update:**

I added:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
```

to my php script and got the same output as what was returned from ldapsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and the short of it is that the client's firewall was set to allow the connection but it was set with a different protocol so the deep packet inspection was knocking it down.  Hopefully if this every happens to someone else this will be helpful.